# Need to move several hundred Structure entries to a new template/template_id

Tags: database, structure

A component of a site I am building has changed and as a result I need to move the entries over to a new template. It looks like this template data is stored in exp_sites > site_pages.

How would you approach this? Not looking to manually update 300+ entries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We also provide this script in the docs: http://buildwithstructure.com/documentation/how_can_i_batch_update_templates_for_existing_entries/

Answer (score 3):

I suggest copy/pasting the serialized array from the `site_pages` column and using an [**online generator**](http://blog.tanist.co.uk/files/unserialize/index.php) to unserialize it. Then copy the unserialized array over to a text editor to find/replace the old `template_id` with the new the `template_id`.

The array contains a URI array & Template array. The template array is the last array. So look for `[1] => 4` which is `[entry_id] => template_id`

I would do a find and replace just for `template_id`: `=> 5` to `=> XX`

As far as serializing the array, I haven't found a online generator to make it easy. You may just need to create a template and enable PHP to serialize it for you, then copy/paste it back into the `site_pages` column.

Always backup first!

#### Update

I just found this script to [**batch update entries**](https://structure.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/414-need-to-batch-change-entry-template-association).

#### 2nd Update

Added the two lines of code for the updating the old template id with the new. Should save a couple clicks

```
<?php
/**
* Batch reset template_id for Structure entries
*/

$str = base64_decode("PASTE-VALUE-FROM_site_pages_FIELD-HERE");
$arr = unserialize ($str);
$old_template_id = PASTE-OLD-TEMPLATE-ID-HERE; //e.g. 3;
$new_template_id = PASTE-NEW-TEPLATE-ID-HERE;//e.g. 24;

// Set new template_id
foreach( $arr[1]['templates'] as $key => $template_id )
{
   if ($template_id == $old_template_id)        
      $arr[1]['templates'][$key] = $new_template_id;
}

// Output
print '<pre>';
print_r($arr);
print '</pre>';

// Serialize & encode
$new_arr = serialize($arr);
$new_str = base64_encode($new_arr);

// Output for copy/paste
print "<textarea rows='100' cols='80'>";
print $new_str;
print "</textarea>";

exit;
?>
```

Comment: I couldn't get this script to work, but the version Travis shared below did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, that's the update script. I was unaware they had that in their docs. Glad you got it working.

Comment: No offense intended in the downvote, but Travis' answer uses official documentation to provide a working solution.

Comment: It's the effort that counts. If I wanted to, I could add the two lines of code that it's missing to be correct, but I left as is. Plus Wedodan just needs to mark Travis's answer correct to supersede my answer.